# Use of panda .loc function in order to select a specific data within a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a dataset which can be found on this website: http://tennis-data.co.uk/alldata.php. It gathers outcomes of both WTA and ATP tennis games over several years.

I would like to find how many sets did the player “ Federer R.” win during the years 2016 and 2017, and for this I used the .loc function as shown below:

```
df = df_atp.loc[df_atp["Date"].between("01/01/2016", "31/12/2017"), ['Winner', 'Wsets']]
print(df)
```

When I print df, here is the result: (part of it since the whole result was very long)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GBgU.png)

I think I'm on the right path, but I want to specifically have only Federer on my results, but like the image shows it I have every other players. I have tried to add `["Federer R."]` at the end of the .loc function but it only gives me an error.

What could I add to the .loc function in order to have only Federer in the results?

Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: What is the code with "Federer R." that threw the error, and what was the error?

Comment: @Zorgoth the code that throws an error is this one: 

df = df_atp.loc[df_atp["Date"].between("01/01/2016", "31/12/2017", inclusive=True), ['Winner', 'Wsets']]["Federer R."]

The error is: " KeyError: 'Federer R.' "

Comment: That's because `df_atp.loc[df_atp["Date"].between("01/01/2016", "31/12/2017", inclusive=True), ['Winner', 'Wsets']]` is a DataFrame with two columns, Winner and Wsets.

Comment: Can I add a third one?

Comment: Is 'Federer R.' a column of the original dataframe? Or are you looking for Federer R. in the Winner column or some other column?

Comment: No it's not. It's a value inside the column 'Winner'. And I don't know how to extract Federer R. out of this column for the .loc function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df_atp.loc[df_atp["Date"].between("01/01/2016", "31/12/2017"), ['Winner', 'Wsets']]
df = df[df['Winner'] == 'Federer R.']
print(df)
```

is the most readable way to do it. You could also do

```
df = df_atp.loc[df_atp["Date"].between("01/01/2016", "31/12/2017") & (df['Winner'] == 'Federer R.'), ['Winner', 'Wsets']]
```

to do it in one line, but I'd favor the first approach for legibility.

Answer (score 0):

When "querying" a dataframe, consider the use of [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) as it can offer a performance improvement compared with other options.